# Multiple inner joins in pymysql

Tags: python, sql, inner-join, pymysql

I am attempting to select multiple columns from three tables in pymysql, and inner join them. I don't understand what is going wrong when I add the second inner join. I feel like it's a simple syntax mistake, but I just can't see it.

This works.

```
q1='''SELECT a.SUBJECT_ID, a.HADM_ID, a.ADMITTIME, p.GENDER, p.DOB, c.ITEMID,
FROM ADMISSIONS as a INNER JOIN PATIENTS as p ON a.SUBJECT_ID=p.SUBJECT_IDd;'
res1=curs.execute(q1)
curs.fetchall()
```

This doesn't work, and I can't see the mistake.

```
q1='''SELECT a.SUBJECT_ID, a.HADM_ID, a.ADMITTIME, p.GENDER, p.DOB, c.ITEMID,
FROM ADMISSIONS as a INNER JOIN PATIENTS as p ON a.SUBJECT_ID=p.SUBJECT_ID
FROM CHARTEVENTS as c INNER JOIN ON ADMISSIONS as a c.SUBJECT_ID=a.SUBJECT_ID;'''
res1=curs.execute(q1)
curs.fetchall()
```

The resulting error

> ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM ADMISSIONS as a INNER JOIN PATIENTS as p ON a.SUBJECT_ID=p.SUBJECT_ID\nFROM ' at line 2")

Comment: You can't have table alias `a` twice.

Comment: There is a trailing comma before `FROM`.

Comment: One FROM too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL error messages are very exact. They point directly to the (first) problem.

Remove the comma

```
c.ITEMID, FROM ADMISSIONS
        ^-------------------------------here
```

But after the join you try to select from another table. That won't work. You have to join them all.

```
FROM ADMISSIONS as a 
INNER JOIN PATIENTS as p ON a.SUBJECT_ID=p.SUBJECT_ID
FROM CHARTEVENTS as c <------------------------------------------NO!
INNER JOIN ON ADMISSIONS as a c.SUBJECT_ID=a.SUBJECT_ID
```